# Hugo syntax highlighting not changing

Tags: syntax-highlighting, hugo

I am using Hugo v0.58.3 with Chroma highlighting.

I have read the instructions about using this command  `hugo gen chromastyles --style=vs > syntax.css` to download the style sheet I want. I use it to overwrite the theme/sometheme/static/css/syntax.css

I have tried a few different styles but changing them seem to have no impact.

I have added two parameters to the `config.toml`

```
 pygmentsCodeFences = true
 pygmentsUseClasses = true
```

My source code is highlighted like this -

```
{{< highlight csharp >}}
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.//snip
{{< /highlight >}}
```

No matter what syntax.css I download, no change occurs on the page.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an example someone can point me to that shows this working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone else who finds this post, here is the problem I was having.

I was using the "Beautiful Hugo" theme with their example app.

In the `config.toml` I had -

```
pygmentsCodeFences = true
pygmentsUseClasses = true
```

But the example `config.toml` also had -

```
useHLJS = true
```

The `head.html` had -

```
{{- if .Site.Params.useHLJS }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "css/highlight.min.css" | absURL }}" />
{{- else -}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "css/syntax.css" | absURL }}" />
{{- end -}}
```

loading the `highlight.min.css` instead of `syntax.min`.

Comment: perfect! It worked with doks, Just need like that.

Comment: In much saltier terms: The Hugo example app uses HLJS, but the documentation instructs people to generate stylesheets with Chroma. This then fails to work out of the box, and you've gotta hope to find this answer.